# Java, JIT and switching between execution modes

Tags: jit, async-profiler

In Java HotSpot methods can be executed in different modes:

1. Interpreter
2. JITed C1 (different levels)
3. JITed C2

Specific mode is determined by `CallDispatcher`, as it is presented here: https://youtu.be/oH4_unx8eJQ?t=1326.
Where can I find `CallDispatcher` in OpenJDK source? And, is it the way to track this dispatcher to know in what mode a specific method is executed right now?